# Loading html source using htmltext in TextField in ActionScript 3.0

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash

I need to update a text field with provided html source. If we have code which has only few tags such as break tags. But, in case of source code having double quotes(") for representing fields such as font-family its not working.

Please help me.

TIA

Answer (score 0):

I expect "font-family" is plain unsupported by the limitations of HTML engine within Flash/TextField. [Check the manual](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/text/TextField.html#htmlText) for the complete set of supported HTML tags and parameters within TextFields.